# When parsing a string using a string stream, it extracts a new line character

Tags: c++, string, performance, parsing, stringstream

**Description of the program :** The program must read in a variable amount of words until a sentinel value is specified ("#" in this case).  It stores the words in a vector array.

**Problem :** I use a getline to read in the string and parse the string with a stringstream.  My problem is that the stringstream is not swallowing the new line character at the end of each line and is instead extracting it.

Some solutions I have thought of is to cut off the last character by creating a subset or checking if the next extracted word is a new line character, but I feel there is a better cost efficient solution such as changing the conditions for my loops.

I have included a minimized version of the overall code that reproduces the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   const int MAX_LIST_SIZE = 1000;
   string str;
   string list[MAX_LIST_SIZE];
   int numWords = 0;

   // program starts here
   getline(cin, str);          // read innput
   stringstream parse(str);    // use stringstream to parse input

   while(str != "#")           // read in until sentinel value
   {
       while(!parse.fail())    // until all words are extracted from the line    
       {
           parse >> list[numWords];    // store words
           numWords++;
       }
       getline(cin,str);      // get next line
       parse.clear();
       parse.str(str);
   }

   // print number of words
   cout << "Number of words : " << numWords << endl;
}
```

And a set of test input data that will produce the problem

**Input:**

```
apples oranges mangos
bananas 
pineapples strawberries
```

**Output:**

```
Number of words : 9
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Number of words : 6
```

I would appreciate any suggestions on how to deal with this problem in an efficient manner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic for parsing out the stream isn't quite correct. `fail()` only becomes true *after* a `>>` operation fails, so you'll doing an extra increment each time. For example:

```
   while(!parse.fail())  
   {
       parse >> list[numWords];    // fails
       numWords++;                 // increment numWords anyway
   }                           // THEN check !fail(), but we incremented already!
```

All of these operations have returns that you should check as you go to avoid this problem:

```
while (getline(cin, str)) { // fails if no more lines in cin
    if (str != "#") {       // doesn't need to be a while
        stringstream parse(str);
        while (parse >> list[numWords]) { // fails if no more words
            ++numWords;                   // *only* increment if we got one!
        }
    }
}
```

Even better would be to not use an array at all for the list of words:

```
std::vector<std::string> words;
```

Which can be used in the inner loop:

```
std::string temp;
while (parse >> temp) {
    words.push_back(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The increment on numwords happens one more time than you intend at the end of each line.  Use a std::vector< std::string > for your list.  Then you can use list.size().